# TortoiseGit: go back to previous version

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I have installed TortoiseGit. I've commit an initial version of my files. But when I do a change and commit again:

1. Right click
2. Click `Git commit -> "master"`

in the log I only see my actual version and the initial commit.

How can I see all versions of my files?

Comment: I don't know tortoise git, but, haven't you forgotten to `git add` your modifications? `git commit` only commits the changes you have staged with `git add`

Comment: have you checked "amend" for some reason (when committing)?

Comment: Screen shots would help.

Comment: @mnagel: Yes. That was the problem (thx)

Answer (score 2):

[mnagel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2536029/mnagel) points out the option "amend" being incorrectly selected (meaning it won't create a new commit, but modify the existing one)

[image: commit]

Note that only recently (end 2012) did the commit amend of TortoiseGit allow to modify the comment only without modifying any file: [issue 1472](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1472).
But in the OP's case, files are selected by default, which means, with the "amend" checkbox, that will add the modification **to the current commit**.